# React native testing show component when logged

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

i am learning jest and react-native-testing. I have a profile file like this:

```
...
const Profile = () => {
  const userInfo = useSelector(state => state.user);

  if(userInfo.isLogged) {
    return (
        <LoggedUI />
    )
  } else {
    return (
        <RegisterUI />
    )
  }
};

...
```

How can I test the render loggedui when state logged is true ?

```
  it('Should Render only the LoggedUI', () => {
    if(reduxState.isLogged === 1) .... (only exp.)
  });

  it('Should Render only the RegisterUI', () => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component with an store provider ->
[Guide](https://medium.com/@lucksp_22012/dont-use-mock-store-use-your-real-store-b319d7e4e22e)